# Highcharts Drilldown How Do I Keep Drilldown Same Size

Tags: highcharts

I've created a [column chart](https://assessment.jefferson.kyschools.us/DMC/District%20Datacard/ddReferrals) that you can drill into. The problem is that there are many columns of data when you drill. How do I keep the widths and overall size of the drilled data the same as the main chart and make the plot region scrollable instead?

As you can see I've tried making the the div containing the chart a max width, hoping that would force and overflow...but not such luck.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="ctReferrals" style="max-width: 500px; overflow-x: auto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>


function loadChart() {
    refChart = new Highcharts.chart('ctReferrals', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'whiteSmoke',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total # of Referrals by School Level'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'By Year'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categoriesSL,
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                useHtml: true,
                text: '<strong># Referrals</strong>'
            }
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderRadius: 5,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            var schoolLevel = this.schoolLevel;
                            var schoolID_alt = this.schoolID_alt;

                            if (schoolID_alt == 0) { // drill down
                                if (schoolLevel == "01") 
                                    setChart(categoriesElem, [pyElem, cyElem]);
                                else if (schoolLevel == "02")
                                    setChart(categoriesMid, [pyMid, cyMid]);
                                else if (schoolLevel == "03")
                                    setChart(categoriesHigh, [pyHigh, cyHigh]);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(categoriesSL, [pySL, cySL]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: dataLabels[0],
            data: pySL
        }, {
            name: dataLabels[1],
            data: cySL
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` properties for `xAxis` and toggle scrollbar from Highstock on drill-events:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        drilldown: function() {
            this.update({
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, false);
        },
        drillupall: function() {
            this.update({
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
},
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 2
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xtg5Lu20/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

Comment: Thank you sir!  I have not used the highstock portion of highcharts before, that was the missing piece.  I need to solve for how to change the categories now on the drilldown, but I think with a little research I should figure it out..thanks again!!